# adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (40);

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working with android studio and when I run my app no devices show.

I ran q cmd with the following command: `adb devices`

to receive the following error:

```
adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (40); killing...
could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

I am not using Genymotion or any other emulator.

Comment: Maybe, this helps? https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232860/340401

Comment: Also, if you're absolutely stuck like I was, try a different host device or new installation instead of giving up! → https://android.stackexchange.com/a/234460/340401